# C++ Access a Base Class's virtual function through a derived object

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, virtual

I'm attempting to create a text-based RPG for my Adv. Programming course and I'm a bit unsure about the polymorphism. I'm building this in pieces and currently I'm trying to get a visual display going based on a prior assignment that involved drawing colored characters to the console via coordinates to create a map. So I have this main:

```
#include "Map.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    ColorMap* _map = new ColorMap(handle, "north");

}
```

and I want to point to the base class's function populateMap, and then access the derived class's populateMap. Here is the header for reference

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Map
{
public:
    Map(HANDLE handle, string direction);
    ~Map(){};

    virtual void update();
    virtual void populateMap();

    void drawPoint(int x, int y) const;

protected:
    HANDLE mHandle;
    char mMap[15][15];
    char mWall;
    char mSpace;
    string mIncomingDirection;
};

class ColorMap : public Map
{
public:
    ColorMap(HANDLE handle, string direction);
    ~ColorMap(){};

    virtual void update();
    virtual void populateMap(); 

    void drawMap();

private:
    int mColor;
};
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `_map->populateMap()`

Comment: Your base class is missing a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need ColorMap implementation to *extend* the base implementation: Your ColorMap's populateMap() implementation should go:

```
void ColorMap::populateMap() {
    Map::populateMap(); // first call the base class
    // now do your things...
}
```

If you have

```
Map *m=new ColorMap(...);

m->populateMap();
```

That will call the derived class method.... However from within that method you can still access the parent class version of the method and run it (before, after or in-between) the rest of the code.

Comment: The ColorMap must also have a virtual destructor if you're going to create a derived object dynamically.

Comment: Why is it Map and then ColorMap and not ColorMap *m=new ColorMap, like I have it?

Comment: @user3523222 I wanted to emphasize that you can call the child class method through a pointer of the base class.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear *where* you want to access the base class' method, but you can do this:

```
_map->Map::populateMap(); // calls base class member function
_map->populateMap();      // calls derived class member function
```

Comment: Just wondering... Did you actually ever use something like `_map->Map::populateMap();` ?

Comment: @Sambuca I have, but I never used it myself. I would say it is a sign of code-smell.

Answer (score 0):

Have your Colormap constructor pass the arguments to the base constructor.
Once virtual delared in base class, derived classes don't need to declare virtual again.